# Brod: Every brod_group_subscriber_v2 needs its own brod client

Tags: apache-kafka, erlang, kafka-consumer-api

*DISCLAIMER: This question is specifically about the Erlang/OTP Kafka Client library [Brod](https://github.com/klarna/brod) (No Tag available yet)*

I am trying to establish three consumer groups, one should write messages just plain to the console, another one should update a state representing API with certain messages, and the third one should store every message into a long term database (crate). I use a supervisor to start three according brod_group_subscriber_v2 (see [this GIST](https://gist.github.com/pinkerltm/8c8458830b8d2047a8d796fb3cfefc28)). If I also start three brod (kafka) clients first and attach each group subscriber its own client, everything works perfectly so that offsets are commited to Kafka for every group and reads start from the latest commited offset.

If I use only one client (as it should be possible and intended according to the Brod docs and issues, see [Reference](https://github.com/klarna/brod/issues/124) by zmstone), only the last group in my CHILD_SPEC works, both other do not receive handle_message calls.

At the moment starting a client for every group is not an issue for me, as there are only three. But as our project grows, we plan to establish a couple of consumer groups, and I don't really think that it might be a good idea to run 20 to 30 brod clients and blocking ressources for each of them.